# ctrl + enter doesn't work after installing resharper

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper

I installed Resharper in visual studio 2013, but <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> (Insert a blank line above the cursor) doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resharper re-maps <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to Resharper_ForceCompleteItem. To get it back just map it back to `Edit.LineOpenAbove` (in `Tools`->`Options`->`Environment`->`Keyboard` in Visual Studio)

Alternatively, if you know the Vi keys then install the [VsVim Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329) and use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to insert above and <kbd>O</kbd> to insert below the cursor.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem happened without installing ReSharper:

go

Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard

then select 'Visual Studio 6' from 'Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme'